# protobuf-net serializing Dictionary<string,object>

Tags: protobuf-net

I try to serialize a Dictionary< string,object > ,  which is a property  of a ServiceStack Response DTO, using the ProtoBufServiceClient.

Simple objects tested   ( string,DateTime, decimal, boolean)

I get an InvalidOperationException from protobuf-net, saying that "the handler for system.object is not defined"

Is there a solution for this problem. I have read that protobuf-net support generic Dictionaries.

I want to transfer a dynamic column-store and this kind of dictionary is required.

Using Json.Net, I can serialize in a string the dictionary, but I would like to avoid this workaround.

thx

Comment: protobuf-net *does not like* `object`... it wants (no, needs) to understand the schema...

Comment: @MarcGravell , why Json.Net can serialize such Dictionary.  I know everything is different, but it seems that there is a way to do it.

Comment: I'm happy for it; but, it is a different format, and different rules apply